# Has any music act ever topped the Beatles in sales?

Tags: 20th-century, music, popular-culture, 21st-century

[image]
<sup>The Beatles in 1965. *Source: Wikipedia*</sup>

[Elvis Presley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley) is widely hailed as the [King of Rock and Roll](https://www.rockhall.com/inductees/elvis-presley), but in [1966 John Lennon said](https://www.thevintagenews.com/2016/11/23/john-lennon-said-the-beatles-were-more-popular-than-jesus/) the Beatles were "[more popular than Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_popular_than_Jesus)" in a [London Evening Standard interview](http://www.beatlesinterviews.org/db1966.0304-beatles-john-lennon-were-more-popular-than-jesus-now-maureen-cleave.html).

Based on record sales, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_music_artists) and this [Business Insider article](https://www.businessinsider.com/best-selling-music-artists-of-all-time-2016-9#9-pink-floyd-75-million-units-42) of top music acts would certainly *seem* to bear that out (but Wiki has the caveat that several mega-artists are not included in their list).

Elvis may always be the King, but the Beatles outsold him considerably, and may well have been "more popular than Jesus" with the popular culture youth in the 1960's. But **has any music act in modern history (20th to 21st centuries) ever been bigger than the Beatles** (worldwide, in number of recordings sold, on any and all media including wax, vinyl, tape, CD, and digital downloads)?

Comment: Is this worldwide or just the U.S.?

Comment: @KillingTime worldwide - total number of records sold would be the only measurable metric for comparison

Comment: If you're going purely on (verified) sales, doesn't the Wikipedia article answer the question?

Comment: @KillingTime - verified sales is a paid-for metric.  Not everyone pays to have their sales volumes "certified." It is an artificial measure if looking for who truly has the most record sales in history.

Comment: What is a "record"? What is "sold"? Seriously.

Comment: @AaronBrick yes that is a valid question, as "record" now includes a vinyl album or single, cassette or 8-track tape, CD, or digital / mp3 downloads (all of these count, total body of recorded work on any listening medium). Sold would be copies in public circulation (unpirated, which can't easily be tracked or counted anyway).

Comment: @KillingTime what exactly do you not understand in the word 'worldwide' ?

Comment: @Jos The original question didn't specify 'worldwide', it was edited in response to my comment, perhaps you should read the edit history before you comment.

Comment: @KillingTime Well, in America 'world championships football' are played with 1 country participating. Most Americans seem to think anyone else has a tail. Call it a reputation. ;-)

Comment: I feel the inclusion of the Jesus comparison is irrelevant to the question (which boils down to "has any music act in modern history ever been bigger than the Beatles"). As can be seen by JMS' answer, it is positively distracting.

Comment: How do you compare vinyl sales to streaming or other forms of download? Are you going by income? It's probable that more people internationally listen to One Direction or BTS today than listened to the Beatles in the 1960s, purely because huge international markets like China are now open to pop music.

Comment: If you combine ALL the gospel releases ever, plus all the books plus the weekly meetings attended by Christ fans, I'd say Jesus is bigger.

Comment: @DevSolar - thanks, good edit. Yes perhaps that was a distraction from the real question. John Lennon certainly found it a distraction as well, but I feel his comments were grossly misunderstood by most.  But that's another topic (and probably a Social Sciences question, not History) :-)

Comment: @ClintEastwood sorry for the distraction in my Question. John Lennon's comments about the Beatles being more popular than Jesus was just meant to "set the stage" of the question about the huge success of the Beatles, eclipsing even the King of Rock-and-Roll, and the King of Kings (which would then make the Beatles not only a tough act to follow, but a nearly impossible act to surpass). But just briefly on that distraction, Lennon meant that the time a teenager spent with the Beatles was more than the time they spent "with Jesus" - Lennon was merely observing, not bragging.

Comment: @StuartF the question would be with regards to purchases of content by the public rather than merely freely listening (whether over the air like radio or free streaming from the internet). A purchase is a purchase and is recorded as a sale, whether it's via clicks or bricks (purchased digital content or vinyl / CD bought in a store or online).

Comment: Not really my area of expertise, but I wonder whether you'd define popularity as maximum audience at one point in time, say the 1960 for Elvis & the Beatles, or cumulative audience.  So you have rock groups like the Rolling Stones still touring & selling new recordings 56 years after their first tour (per Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones_concerts#Concert_tour_chronology )  And of course Bach, Beethoven, and others still sell several centuries after their demise :-)

Comment: @jamesqf while I would certainly esteem Bach, Beethoven, Mozart, Hayden, Brahms, Chopin, Schubert, _et al_ in a much higher class than the Beatles and the King, they are also in a _different_ class (not recording artists, but composers). I considered looking for audience statistics as a separate comparison measure but for this question the only numbers that need to be evaluated are total number of sales (not in dollars but in records / tapes / CD's / downloads, etc.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Beatles sold the most overall albums [in the US at least](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/music/50-best-selling-music-artists-all-time-bands-singers-musicians-richest-beatles-a7946531.html) but their best selling album is only [number 12](http://mentalfloss.com/article/565257/sesame-street-new-music) as far as best selling albums go.  So it's going to depend a lot on how exactly you define "biggest".

Comment: @KillingTime Edit history notwithstanding, why would it be just the US? Just because _you're_ in the US? The Beatles weren't... plenty of people here aren't...

Comment: Possibly The Bee Gees' Saturday Night Fever album released in 1977-78, during the height of the Disco era.  While Disco was a short lived phenomenon, it essentially bankrolled The Bee Gees-(who, prior to Disco, had limited worldwide fame) to international stardom and likely surpassing The Beatles in terms of overall sales.

Comment: And KISS may have also surpassed The Beatles in terms of overall sales.  KISS was as hugely successful as The Bee Gees during the 70's.

Comment: I barely remember the late 70's, though from what I remember, The Bee Gees and Kiss were enormously popular during that time period......(as well as Fleetwood Mac's Rumors album and tour).

Comment: Other contenders for surpassing The Beatles in terms of overall sales, would be Pink Floyd and their landmark albums, "Dark Side of the Moon"-(1973) & The Wall-(1979-80), Michael Jackson's Thriller-(1982-83) and probably the long and very successful career of Madonna, who had hit records and tours throughout the 80's, 90's and even into the 2000's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### SHORT ANSWER

> **Has any music act ever topped the Beatles in sales?**

There is probably only one likely contender - Elvis Presley - but it is highly unlikely that we'll ever know for sure.

One problem is how to calculate sales (i.e. singles vs. EPs vs. albums vs. double albums vs. music videos vs. streaming). Another problem is the reliability and completeness of data from record labels. As *Spencer* has pointed out in a comment below, citing sales value would seem to be the logical way to get around the first problem, but such data does not appear to be available. The music industry has traditionally cited sales in units and recording companies are cagey about value (and have also been known to inflate figures for units sold).

---

### COUNTING PROBLEMS

There are numerous problems in arriving at a total, not least of which is how sales of albums and singles are counted. Should one album sale be equivalent to one single sale, or to the six, eight, ten or even twelve singles that can fit on one album?

Also, how does one count the numerous multi-artist compilation albums that include one (or maybe several) songs from the Beatles or Elvis Presley (or whoever else one is trying to tally the sales of)?

And how can one be sure of numbers when some record companies refuse to release sales figures, while others may well be inflating numbers for publicity reasons?

These are just a few of the problems...

---

### THE NUMBERS

Of the more than 30 sites I've looked at which give estimates, very few cite any sources or explain how the numbers they quote were arrived at. For what they are worth, here are some examples (roughly from highest estimates to lowest).

For those who want the most realistic data, go to headings 3 & 4 below.

#### 1. 'Hard to believe'

**The Beatles:** 1.6 billion singles sold in the US + 600 million albums worldwide. *Source: [Beatles by the Numbers](https://www.infoplease.com/us/arts-entertainment/beatles-numbers). These numbers are also given by [cbsnews.com](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/the-beatles-by-the-numbers/) (2014). Of all the numbers cited, this 1.6 billion US singles is the most suspect. Even 1.6 billion units worldwide would be hard to believe so this estimate seems to be fanciful at best.*

**Elvis Presley:** 1.5 billion, according to Sony BMG (circa 2016). *Source: [For The Billionth And The Last Time : Lifting the Lid on the King's record sales](https://www.elvis.com.au/presley/one-billion-record-sales.shtml). The author of this article disputes this figure and, as with the Beatles 1.6 billion, seems unrealistic.*

#### 2. 'Just a convenient round number?'

**Elvis Presley:** "sales of Presley records have passed that coveted one billion milestone" (2016). Source: [For The Billionth And The Last Time : Lifting the Lid on the King's record sales](https://www.elvis.com.au/presley/one-billion-record-sales.shtml)

**The Beatles:** Over one billion discs and tapes (EMI estimate, March 2001). **Elvis Presley:** 1 billion sales worldwide. *Sources: [Best-selling group](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/best-selling-group) and [Best-selling solo artist](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/best-selling-solo-artist)*

**Elvis Presley:** 1.1 billion, **Bing Crosby:** 900 million. *Source: [The Elvis presley - Bing Crosby Comparison Page](http://www.waynesthisandthat.com/elvisbing.html)*

**Michael Jackson:** 1 billion (Dec 2015). *[Source: Michael Jackson's 'Thriller' First Ever 30X Multi-Platinum RIAA Certification](https://www.riaa.com/michael-jacksons-thriller-first-ever-30x-multi-platinum-riaa-certification/?fbclid=IwAR2R6G-vBATgDyTJg-33dXN3CvZS4mzdEU0cM1onDS8ER-RHikmoMY-i3zo)*

**Bing Crosby:** "close to one billion records, tapes, compact discs and digital downloads around the world." *[Source: Bing by the Numbers. His Amazing Music Records](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/americanmasters/bing-crosby-records-in-music/3528/)*

#### 3. Probably more realistic (but method of calculation not explained)

**The Beatles:** 545 million units worldwide (October 1972). *Source: [Beatles Record Sales Around The World](http://www.beatlesradio.com/beatles-record-sales), citing *Billboard 84, October 21**

**The Beatles:** 257.7 million, **Elvis Presley:** 206.8 million. *Source: [Top-selling artists worldwide from 1954 to 2016, based on certified sales (in millions)](https://www.statista.com/statistics/271174/top-selling-artists-in-the-united-states/). Note: this site does give a source but it is hidden behind a paywall.*

#### 4. Probably more realistic (with method of calculation explained)

**The Beatles:** 419,531,000 as of Mar 2017, **Michael Jackson:** 334,235,000 (as of Sep 2017), **Elvis Presley:** 318,224,000 (as of Sep 2018), **Queen** 274,320,000 as of Jan 2020. All figures are in CSPC ([Commensurate Sales to Popularity Concept](https://chartmasters.org/2016/03/the-commensurate-sales-to-popularity-concept-cspc-introduction/)), a method which attempts to relate the different formats (albums, singles, streaming etc.). *Data source: [Best selling artists of all-time](https://chartmasters.org/best-selling-artists-of-all-time/).*

---

### ALSO OF INTEREST

The article *[Who was the world's biggest music act of all time?](https://tsort.info/music/faq_greatest_act.htm)* presents an interesting interactive graphic which allows one to modify different parameters when calculating sales (e.g. value of albums versus singles). Most combinations put the Beatles on top, but when singles and album sales are both counted as one sale, Elvis Presley sometimes heads the list.

The article *[Is Elvis the Biggest Selling Recording Artist? - Sorting Out Records Sales Stats & RIAA Rules](https://www.elvis.com.au/presley/is-elvis-the-biggest-selling-recording-artist.shtml)* provides a sharp critique of the RIAA and argues strongly that Elvis Presley is several hundred million ahead of the Beatles. The authors present a convincing case in parts, but they are also connected to RCA records (Presley's main record label) and, at the same as saying we should stop arguing about who has sold the most records, insist that Elvis comes out top.

The article *[Did "Thriller" really sell a hundred million copies](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/did-thriller-really-sell-a-hundred-million-copies)* presents some interesting insights on how sales are miscounted.

The article *[Who was bigger: Elvis Presley or The Beatles?](https://daytrippin.com/2015/12/01/who-was-bigger-elvis-presley-or-the-beatles/)* says that the Beatles outsold Elvis Presley in the US and then claims that:

> When figuring sales of singles, EPs and albums worldwide, many
> historians believe that Elvis is the best-selling artist period.

However, it gives no sources and I haven't found anything to confirm this. In fact, *Baker's Biographical Dictionary of Musicians, Volume 1* mentions

> The Beatles' unprecedented commercial success

Comment: Thank you Lars!  Great info!  I'm curious about the [Bing Crosby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_Crosby) stats... [Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/stanley-fish/frank-sinatra-bing-crosby_b_8256996.html) said "Crosby had 43 number-one hits — more than the Beatles and Elvis put together. His career total of record sales tops one billion albums sold, making him the most popular singer ever. “White Christmas” alone has sold more than one-hundred million copies and is the all-time best-selling single." ... (cont'd) ...

Comment: Also [PBS](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/americanmasters/bing-crosby-records-in-music/3528/) said: "Bing Crosby scored 41 No. 1 records (43 including the second and third chart-toppings of “White Christmas”) — more than The Beatles (24) and Elvis Presley (18). His recordings reached the charts 396 times, more than Frank Sinatra (209) and Elvis Presley (149) combined. Bing’s closest rival is Paul Whiteman (220) with whose orchestra he sang early in his career. Bing’s records hit the Top 10 203 times and spent 173 weeks in the No. 1 spot." ... (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) ... and just for fun, [Town Topics](http://www.towntopics.com/wordpress/2017/05/03/dreaming-a-little-dream-with-bing-crosby-nothing-is-dated-on-john-lennons-jukebox/) has a fun article on Bing and the Beatles (Bing was quick to tip his hat to both Elvis and the Beatles - he was very magnanimous ... I miss Bing!) :-)

Comment: @KerryL I think the Bing Crosby figures are more suspicious than most for a number of reasons. The market was much smaller for most of his career - population, people owning a player, limited international sales. Also, album sales didn't really start to take off until the late 1950s (later outside the US) so 1 billion album sales is *really* suspect, even by music industry standards. Finally, there is general agreement on 50 million + sales of 'White Christmas' (it's also the figure cited by Guinness) so 100 million also looks very suspect.

Comment: Seems reasonable - except Bing’s sales didn’t stop when he ended recording. They continue to this day (also true for the Beatles and the King) :-)

Comment: These numbers will never be eclipsed for the simple reason that the industry has moved to streaming.  Simply put: people don't buy as much music as they used to, and the trend is [continuing downward](https://www.riaa.com/u-s-sales-database/).   In addition, the majority of sales come from "paid subscriptions", and it's not so easy to apply that to individual artists.

Comment: @GorttheRobot 's comment brings us to the fundamental flaw in this approach: If we are measuring "success" in terms of "sales", why then are we measuring "sales" in terms of individual singles and albums, and not sales in terms of money?

Comment: @Spencer Good point. The problem here is trying to find such data. Every site I've found gives unit sales, perhaps because that is the data that the original sources (such as record companies) provide. I did see one claim that Pink Floyd are the most commercially successful band of all time - a dollar figure was given (sorry, I can't remember how much as this was some time ago) but this would presumably have included income from concerts and merchandizing.

Answer (score 0):

USA sales of 1.6 billion singles is grossly exaggerated. As the Beatles released around 60 singles while together, average sales per single would have to have been more than 26 million! The recognised source for record/CD sales in the US is the [RIAA](https://www.riaa.com/). It has the Beatles accredited singles at under 30 million. On the albums front the Beatles are undisputed leaders in sales.

Regarding Bing Crosby his sales were undoubtedly huge but the US population was much smaller at his peak and many of his #1 hits were on non-national (regional) charts.

Comment: You are no doubt right that 1.6 billion is exaggerated, but RIAA figures are also contested. Fact is, we'll never know for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has sold 1 billion records, but the fact that the Beatles have had more number 1 albums in the U S (the world's largest market)than any artist has had singles says  a lot. I would say no one has surpassed their sales.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: We prefer answers based on evidence to opinions

Answer (score -3):

Bing Crosby otro fenómeno mundial , Crosby anotó 41 éxitos número uno más que Elvis y Los Beatles.

Google translate suggests,

> Bing Crosby Another worldwide phenomenon, Crosby scored 41 more number one hits than Elvis and The Beatles.

Comment: Welcome! I regret to say that H:SE is an English language site, and we strongly prefer answer supported by evidence. Can you translate and provide supporting references?

Comment: Note that the question is "Has any music act ever topped the Beatles in sales?", not a question of "number one hits"